# Symfony2: FOSRest: Allow route for both "/api/items" and "api/items/{id}"

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

So, I'm trying to create a simple REST api with Symfony2 and the FOSRestBundle.

It's going really well, however I've hit a wall that Google apparantly hasnt been able to answer :)

I understand that this:

```
public function getUsersAction(){
  return 'A list of all the users';
}
```

Will create a route as such:

```
  api_get_users              GET      ANY      ANY    /api/users.{_format}
```

And I know that add a function parameter:

```
public function getUsersAction($id){
  return 'A specific users (with $id) details';
}
```

Will create a route as such:

```
  api_get_users              GET      ANY      ANY    /api/users/{userid}.{_format}
```

However what if I want to make it, so both routes are available (like a proper REST api design)?

I tried doing something like

```
public function getUsersAction($userid = NULL){
```

But it didnt work (not a huge surprise)..

I'm pretty sure that I'm missing a simple piece of the puzzle, but I have no idea what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a `getUserAction($id)` and a `getUsersAction()` (not plural) should work, according to [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.html#implicit-resource-name-definition):

> ```
> class UserController implements ClassResourceInterface
> {
>     // ...
>
>     public function getUsersAction()
>     {} // "get_users"     [GET] /users
>
>     public function getUserAction($slug)
>     {} // "get_user"      [GET] /users/{slug}
>
>     // or when omittig "User":
>
>     public function cgetAction()
>     {} // "get_users"     [GET] /users
>
>     public function getAction($slug)
>     {} // "get_user"      [GET] /users/{slug}
>
>     // ...
> }
> ```

Comment: I dont have enough reputition to vote you up yet - sorry :(